# Incoherent handling of datetime objects in by the DataFrame.to_markdown method

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-datetime

## Main objective

I want to transform a `pandas.DataFrame` with a single column, containing `datetime.datetime` objects, into its markdown representation, using the `pandas.DataFrame.to_markdown` method.

### Issue

The markdown table does not display the date as desired (displays a timestamp instead of the expected `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS`). How can I make it display the date in the usual format?

### Code

```py
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

df:pd.DataFrame = pd.DataFrame({
    "date": [
        datetime(year=2022, month=1, day=1, hour=1, minute=1, second=1),
        datetime(year=2022, month=6, day=2, hour=2, minute=2, second=2),
        datetime(year=2022, month=10, day=3, hour=3, minute=3, second=3)
    ]
})

print(df.to_markdown())
```

Displays

|  | date |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | `1.641e+18` |
| 1 | `1.65414e+18` |
| 2 | `1.66477e+18` |

## Why is this "incoherent"?

When I first had to display this `DataFrame`, I had add one column to it, in which I inserted the year of the corresponding `Timestamp` object. I thus have 2 columns, with respectively `pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp` and `numpy.int64` objects in them.
When converted to markdown, it produced the desired effect by formatting the `Timestamp` as expected.

### Code

```py
# To add after the previous code

df["year"] = df.date.apply(lambda x: x.year)

print(df.to_markdown())
```

Displays

|  | date | year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2022-01-01 01:01:01 | 2022 |
| 1 | 2022-06-02 02:02:02 | 2022 |
| 2 | 2022-10-03 03:03:03 | 2022 |

## Lead

By checking the types by using the `pandas.DataFrame.info` method, and by calling the `type` method on the content of the individual cells, I observed that the types are not always the same. Is it normal?

For instance, the `type` method on the content of a `year` cell will show that these cells contain `numpy.int64` objects, while the `info` method will display the content of the column as `int64`.

Additionally, the `date` column will be shown as filled of `datetime64[ns]` by the `info` method, while the `type` one will say the cells are `pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp`.

Could it have any influence whatsoever?

Comment: Just adding any other column whatsover does seem to lead to the appropriate output. Strange.

Comment: Happy to see it isn't just me! Going into [the code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.4.3/pandas/core/frame.py#L2683-L2735) has not answered my question, I may not be skilled enough...

Comment: I think I have clue: `pd.to_markdown` is using the package `tabulate`. And in it there's a [type-check](https://github.com/gregbanks/python-tabulate/blob/master/tabulate.py#L265), that identifies datetimes by checking if it has an attribute `isoformat`. It also uses `df.values`, a Numpy-array, for the data. So far, so good.

Comment: The problem starts when there are _only_ datetimes in the `df`, because then the `dtype` of `df.values` is  set to `numpy.datetime64`, which doesn't have the `isoformat` attribute. If there's at least one non-datetime column, the `dtype` is set to `object`, ant the datetimes remain `pd.Timestamp` which have this attribute. :((